# Related items in EF in core 2.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

this question is totally about concept, i want to know i'm doing well or wrong.

i'm using EF in core2.1 razor pages, for example, i have blog class ad image class:

```
public class Blog
{
  public int Id { get; set; }  
  public string Title{ get; set; }
  public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

as you see each blog has image, but i didn't add imageId in the blog table, and everything is working well, when i add new blog : i add it's image as follow:

```
Blog.Image = new Image
{
  Path = Value
};
_context.Image.Add(Blog.Image);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

then when i load the blog i can get the image even without adding ImageId in the blog class, is this correct ? i'm doing well ?

and about the concept is it true and should i work with it in the other items ?

actually i did several searches, even MS documents, some of them use Id and the other no, things are not clear.

thanks ..

Comment: Opinion-based. Nevertheless, images are one type of entity you really don't want to set by retrieving it from the db first and then assigning it to a `Blog`. So no, don't do without `ImageId`.

Comment: @GertArnold, this is not related storing images to a DB. Edmond is confused why this workd. Edmond, Have you checked your DB? I believe EF created itself the imageid column on your Blog Table and made the KeyRelation

Comment: @Aldert , yes it did, the ImageId created in shadow, my question was is this method ok to let the EF create the foreign key automatically ? or should i add the Id ?

Comment: You are totally fine when EF is doing this for you.